# Standard deviation translation property proof - confused about mean property

Tags: probability

I need to prove that $$std(x+c) = std(x)$$

I have been trying to use the properties of the mean such as $$mean(x+c) = mean(x) + c$$

I am confused on the following property of the mean, is this statement correct?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N}(x_i - mean(\{x\}))^2 = mean(\{x\}) \\$$

If that is correct, then by the definition of standard deviation, is the following correct?

$$std(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N}(x_i - mean(\{x\}))^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}mean(\{x\})} \\$$

This does not seem right to me.

Here is my previous attempt at the proof, I think I am doing something wrong, this is why I am now attempting with the above property.

$$std(\{x + c\}) = \sqrt{mean(\{((x+c) - mean(\{x\}) + c)^2\})} = \sqrt{mean(\{(x - mean(\{x\}) + 2c)^2\})} = \sqrt{\frac{((x_1 - mean(\{x\}) + 2c))^2) + ((x_2 - mean(\{x\}) + 2c))^2) + ... + ((x_n - mean(\{x\}) + 2c))^2)}{N}}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

std($x$) = $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_i(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{N-1}}$

mean($x + c$) = $\frac{\sum_i (x_i + c)}{N} = \bar{x} + c$

Therefore

std($x+c$) = $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_i(x_i + c - \bar{x} - c)^2}{N-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_i(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{N-1}} = \text{std}(x)$

Answer (score 0):

About

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N}(x_i - mean(\{x\}))^2 = mean(\{x\}) \\$$

Try considering some very simple special cases.  For example, suppose $x$ takes positive & negative values resulting in $mean(\{x\})=0$. The sum will then be positive.  So your  equation that doesn't seem right can't be correct. To derive the equation $$std(x+c)=std(x)$$ try simplifying it by eliminating the square roots and the division by N. Then look closely at the squared deviations of $x+c$ from $mean(x+c)$: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i=N}[(x_i+c) - mean(x+c)]^2$$

Compare to corresponding expression appearing in std(x).